# How to call soap web service from camel rest java DEL

Tags: rest, soap, apache-camel

I am trying to call soap web service from camel rest, from java DSL. but getting server error with 500 response code.

I will receive call from a rest with json data and i have to make call to a third party soap service also i need to process the soap response and send back the response in json formate.

here is my code

```
{
String getCustomerDetailsurl="http://<serverip>/webservice/Service.asmx?op=GetClientDetail&bridgeEndpoint=true";

rest("/customers")
.description("Aviva Mobile  sales customer service")
.consumes("application/json")
.produces("application/json")
 .post().type(ClientRequest.class) // incomming request data
 .route()
 .from("direct:start")
 //.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
  .process(new CustomerProcessor()).marshal().xstream()
.to(getCustomerDetailsurl);
```

Error

```
org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://<serverip>/webservice/Service.asmx?op=GetClientDetail with statusCode: 500
       at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:239) ~[camel-http-2.17.5.jar:2.17.5]
       at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:161) ~[camel-http-2.17.5.jar:2.17.5]
       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.17.5.jar:2.17.5]
       at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145) ~[camel-core-2.17.5.jar:2.17.5]
       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) ~[camel-core-2.17.5.jar:2.17.5]
       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468) ~[camel-core-2.17.5.jar:2.17.5]

}
```

Comment: try to look into camel cxf http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html

Comment: There are many reasons for this. Please do more troubleshooting and get back with more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to look at Server side for what actual error is.
2. You may use some tool like tcp monitor (tcpMon) to see exactly what you send and what you get back.
3. Actually, To use SOAP service it is much better to use SOAP client, rather than raw call through http. Take a look at Camel-CXF component. Then create a CXF endpoint and use it uri in your `.to({cxfEndpointUri})`. CXF will do all SOAP work for you. Maybe you will need to make a little work in its interceptors, like authorization if Server requires it.

P.S. In your code what kind of Exchange.body your `CustomerProcessor` produces? is it a valid for server SOAP Envelope? does it have all what server requires by its contract (WSDL)?